# Como puedo poner dos tarjetas en una misma fila usando material-ui?

Tags: css, material-ui

Como puedo poner dos tarjetas en una misma fila usando material-ui?

Si lo pongo de la siguiente manera me aparece una tarjeta encima de otra...

```
        <Grid container direction="column" justify="flex-start" alignItems="flex-start">
          <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardContent>
      
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así como está escrito el código ahora, solo hay una tarjeta definida. Así que habría que agregar una más para poder alinearlas.

Para que ambas tarjetas estén en la misma fila tendrías que cambiar el `direction="column"` por un `direction="row"`.

Con esos cambios te quedaría así:

```
<Grid container direction="row" justify="flex-start" alignItems="flex-start">
   <Card className={classes.root}>
     <CardContent>
  
     </CardContent>
   </Card>
   <Card className={classes.root}>
     <CardContent>
  
     </CardContent>
   </Card>
 </Grid>
```

Acá en en la documentación de `Material UI` se explica mejor:

https://material-ui.com/es/components/grid/#interactive